# Creating a stored procedure via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a seed DB in my web app, and i was able to create the DB, populate the tables, i'm just stuck at getting the stored procedures to work. Here is what i have so far, but im getting CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.\r\nIncorrect syntax near 'GO'.  I tried with removing the GO's too, and also adding \r\n's between the USE statement and the create procedure with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
StringBuilder sbSP = new StringBuilder();
sbSP.AppendLine("USE [" + txtDBName.Text + "]");
sbSP.AppendLine("GO");
sbSP.AppendLine("CREATE PROCEDURE [spInsertADAuthorization] @AD_Account varchar(255),@AD_SID varchar(255),@AD_EmailAddress varchar(255),@DateImported datetime,@Active bit AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO AD_Authorization (AD_Account, AD_SID, AD_EmailAddress, DateImported, Active) VALUES (@AD_Account,@AD_SID,@AD_EmailAddress,@DateImported,@Active) END");
sbSP.AppendLine("GO");
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSP.ToString(), connection))
                            {
                                connection.Open();
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the USE altogether and just being explicit in the name? `"CREATE PROCEDURE [" + txtDBName + "]..[spInsertADAuthorization] ..."` ??

Comment: Have you considered using Entity Framework Code First and having it generate the database? Raw ADO.NET is a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"GO" is a batch separator. It's not a T-SQL Statement. Remove the "USE" and both "GO" lines and try again.

Comment: ...your connection string will specify what database you're operating on; that's why you don't need that `use` (if the database in your connection string matches the database you want to seed, of course).

Comment: The problem is, the user chooses the DB name so the connection string doesnt know what the name is yet, hence the USE. Now i'm getting "{"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@AD_Account\"."} when get rid of the GO's and the USE.

Comment: Can you use the [`ChangeDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase.aspx) method to change the database for the connection before executing the code to create the SP.

Comment: John is right. In C# for example you first you have to `connection.Open();` `connection.ChangeDatabase(the_name_of_your_catalog);`. After those you can call `yourCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the "GO" command is simply a batch separator which is interpreted by   SSMS.  What you want to do is create the stored procedure as follows:

```
string sql = string.Format("CREATE PROCEDURE [{0}]..[spInsertADAuthorization] @AD_Account varchar(255),@AD_SID varchar(255),@AD_EmailAddress varchar(255),@DateImported datetime,@Active bit AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO AD_Authorization (AD_Account, AD_SID, AD_EmailAddress, DateImported, Active) VALUES (@AD_Account,@AD_SID,@AD_EmailAddress,@DateImported,@Active) END", txtDBName.Text);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this when running it : {"'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@AD_Account\"."}

Comment: I do not see the END statement in this CREATE PROCEDURE

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'USE [DataBase] Go' you can set or change the current database for an open SqlConnection very easily:

```
connection.ChangeDatabase("YourDB");
```

An example:

```
private static void ConctDatabase(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Database: {0}", conn.Database);
        conn.ChangeDatabase("Northwind");
        MessageBox.Show("Database: {0}", conn.Database);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at creating a Database and maintaining versions in your code, you might want to consider using something like the [Migrator Framework](https://github.com/migratordotnet/Migrator.NET) instead of hand writing all that SQL.