# Create a stored procedure in my own SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm developing a website that I do not have remote access to its SQL Server. When I try to create a new procedure in my own database I got stuck this error:

> CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE must be the first statement in a query batch.

That's because of T-SQL scripts containing "GO" statement....

Using the `Server Management Objects` (SMO), the problem still exists for me. How can I create a stored procedure in my database without using `Go` statement and without using SMO?

This is my code:

```
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    string sql = "CREATE Procedure [dbo]......";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Con.Close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code? How you create store procedure?

Comment: Have you tried Execute function? Also is it possible to share sql?

Comment: Please, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659661/creating-a-stored-procedure-via-c-sharp) and the accepted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8659680/982431). The only difference that I can see with your code is that you don't have the `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` code statement.

Comment: @HassanNisar there is no direct accessing to DB.

Comment: @HuorSwords I know but when I remove the "USE" and "GO" line, created SP does not in the my DB.

Comment: @Nasser, I'm not absolutetly sure, but you can define your default database on the connection string. If you define this default database, the `USE` sentence is not neccessary. In example, `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

Comment: I tried it once but I would try one more time. I'll tell you the results.

Comment: I had read it somewhere that one must use "GO" statement (one liner) before `Create Procedure` statement as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I finally found the answer.
You can change the current database for an open SqlConnection very easily:

```
connection.ChangeDatabase("YourDB");
```

An example:

```
private static void ConctDatabase(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Database: {0}", conn.Database);
        conn.ChangeDatabase("Northwind");
        MessageBox.Show("Database: {0}", conn.Database);
    }
}
```