# How to create stored procedure in C#, then *save* it to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been banging my head against a wall for a little while on this one. I know you can create a stored procedure in C# code, that bit's OK. But what I can't figure out is can I then *save* that stored procedure, *onto the SQL Server* - but done via C# code?

Scenario is: I want to create a test database via code, then I want to add a stored procedure to the newly created test database (server side) - again, all done via the same C# code project.

Comment: Why just not do it in SQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possibe. Here I give you a sample example.

```
public partial class InitialEntities : DbMigration  
{  
public override void Up()  
{  
    CreateStoredProcedure(  
        "dbo.InsertEmployee",  
         p => new  
        {  
            Code = p.String(),  
            Name = p.String(),  
            DepartmentId = p.Int(),  
        },  
        body:  
            @"INSERT [dbo].[EmployeeMasters]([Code], [Name], [DepartmentId])  
        VALUES (@Code, @Name, @DepartmentId)  

        DECLARE @EmployeeId int  
        SELECT @EmployeeId = [EmployeeId]  
        FROM [dbo].[EmployeeMasters]  
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [EmployeeId] = scope_identity()  

        SELECT t0.[EmployeeId]  
        FROM [dbo].[EmployeeMasters] AS t0  
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId"  
    );  

    CreateStoredProcedure(  
        "dbo.UpdateEmployee",  
        p => new  
        {  
            EmployeeId = p.Int(),  
            Code = p.String(),  
            Name = p.String(),  
            DepartmentId = p.Int(),  
        },  
        body:  
            @"UPDATE [dbo].[EmployeeMasters]  
        SET [Code] = @Code, [Name] = @Name, [DepartmentId] = @DepartmentId  
        WHERE ([EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId)"  
    );  

    CreateStoredProcedure(  
        "dbo.DeleteEmployee",  
        p => new  
        {  
            EmployeeId = p.Int(),  
        },  
        body:  
            @"DELETE [dbo].[EmployeeMasters]  
        WHERE ([EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId)"  
    );  

}  

public override void Down()  
{  
    DropStoredProcedure("dbo.DeleteEmployee");  
    DropStoredProcedure("dbo.UpdateEmployee");  
    DropStoredProcedure("dbo.InsertEmployee");  
}  
}
```

Without entity framework

```
 StringBuilder sbSP = new StringBuilder();

 sbSP.AppendLine("CREATE PROCEDURE [spInsertADAuthorization] @AD_Account varchar(255),@AD_SID varchar(255),@AD_EmailAddress varchar(255),@DateImported datetime,@Active bit AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO AD_Authorization (AD_Account, AD_SID, AD_EmailAddress, DateImported, Active) VALUES (@AD_Account,@AD_SID,@AD_EmailAddress,@DateImported,@Active) END");
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{

 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sbSP.ToString(), connection))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

[Creating a stored procedure via C# with entityframework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/code-first-stored-procedure-entity-framework-6-0/)

[Creating a stored procedure via C# without entityframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659661/creating-a-stored-procedure-via-c-sharp)

Comment: Definitely a better answer, though this needs EntityFramework right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use the usual `CREATE PROCEDURE` text within your string then execute it through a SqlCommand given that the user of course has permissions to store procedures. Read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659661/creating-a-stored-procedure-via-c-sharp) as it has some details regarding `GO` and `USE` which is often used in the creation of sprocs (and will give you trouble within C#)

Comment: Question is how to create a CLR stored procedure in C# code and not how to create a T-SQL produce via C# code.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Quoting the original question: "...can I then save that stored procedure, onto the SQL Server - but done via C# code?"

Comment: I thought he was referring to CLR stored procedures:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx