# How to check (compile) before create sp from c# to sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

My question is about this question asked before : [How to create stored procedure in C#, then *save* it to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34973095/1439935)

In every case in that question, how can I check, control or compile that sp?
In this situation, I can create a sp that will not be compiled again from SQL server such as if table not exists?

Comment: I usually use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server. I create my stored procedures in SSMS which has better error checking than if you do it in c#.  You can save the stored procedures as a SSQL text file to reuse.  Once the stored procedures are created you can then access then from c#.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the error back to your program. Also, you cannot create same named procedures. You need to delete the old one first. Here's a list of ways with which you can do that.

[Sql Server equivalent to Oracle's CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163246/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-create-or-replace-view)

Pass this first, check for old procedure and delete it. Then create a new procedure.

Comment: Check this question. Here, they need a error message and error code, which you can get from SqlCommand. I think you can implement one of these methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024109/how-can-i-get-an-error-message-that-happens-when-using-executenonquery